# Wpf - how to correctly use MouseEnter, Click, and MouseLeave to change background of a ToggleButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a weird issue with a set of `ToggleButton`s. I am using them for a rating control that looks like the following:

[image: rating control]

Each `ToggleButton` listens to the following events:

```
rating_button.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(rating_button_mouse_entered);
rating_button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(rating_button_clicked);
rating_button.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(rating_button_mouse_left);
```

When the mouse enters over a `ToggleButton`, the `MouseEnter` event sets the `Foreground` of the current and previous `ToggleButton`s to a light yellow like so:

[image: hover and click]

The `MouseLeave` event resets the `Foreground` of all `ToggleButton`s to what it used to be.

The `Click` event is supposed to immediately set the `Foreground` of the current and previous `ToggleButton`s to gold (so the 4 stars in the second image should have the same color as the first image). Now here comes the problem - setting the `Foreground` in this event handler actually does nothing! The backgrounds are not set until `MouseLeave` fires.

If I do not set the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event handlers, the `Foreground` changes immediately in the `Click` handler, which is the desired behavior. However, the hover functionality obviously will not work.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your event handlers you have to set the `Handled` property to `true` if you don't want the event to bubble up from MouseEnter -> Click. So that it won't change the `Foreground` immediately.